# sql changing null to 0

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion-10

I am using a web app to get "Quantity On-hand" for an inventory app. The user is actually allowed to leave the box blank when they submit. I set the SQL table field to default to -1. When I go through the insert routine and then look at the database table the value for an item that was not entered is 0. If there was no entry why didn't the default of -1 fill the field and not 0?

Comment: Are you sure there was no entry? Does your app convert a blank to a 0? Default only work if a NULL is inserted.

Comment: Because the application code does not work like you think it does.

Comment: The default value only applies if the column is not specified in the insert statement.

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: As others mentioned, either the table default or the insert isn't doing what you think it is. Please post the CREATE TABLE ddl and INSERT query so someone can help you figure out which one is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table may be having default value set to 0(Zero) or your code is making it by conversion as int so something like that which is getting zero.

Below is an example it is working as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EMPDetails](
    [EmpID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [EmpName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT(-1),
)
GO

insert into dbo.EMPDetails(EmpName) Values('Umakanta Swain')

select * from dbo.EMPDetails
```

Comment: You explicitly inserted -1. That's different from setting it to the column default which you failed to do in the DDL.